# What to do to explain to user why Ask for sensitive data

Tags: android, instagram-api

I am designing an app that works with instagram API so i should ask the user for his username and password
what should i do to explain it to the user that his data is safe and not sent to anyone other than instagram server
Should i make my app partly open source or what is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a privacy policy for the app so you tell your users all the information of how you collect, store and use their data also you must give them the option to delete their data if they want to go out of your app.
I remember Facebook is already asking the developer about the privacy policy to give them access for using social user's data.

Answer (score 1):

> I am designing an app that works with instagram API so i should ask the user for his username and password

Should you really though? A quick google search shows that the Instragram API provides a flow for authenticating users so you can get an access token without the user having to provide your app specifically with a username or password.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#authorization-window